# Error installing john 1.9.0 using snap

Tags: ubuntu, snap, john-the-ripper

I am trying to install john-the-ripper in Ubuntu 22.04 using the following command:

```
sudo snap install john-the-ripper
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Cannot install "john-the-ripper" :Post
https://api.snapcraft.io//v2/snaps/refresh : Method cannot be allowed
```

I would appreciate for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with your internet.

1. Are you using a VPN or proxy?
2. Is your internet stable?
3. Are you using a laptop? If so, are you connected through ethernet or WiFi?
4. What happens if you do `sudo snap refresh`?

Please update your post and include this info.